# Return layer activations and weights from Tensorflow model in separate threads

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to retrieve an output from a tensorflow model (global *mModel*) loaded in one thread (using *keras.models.model_from_json* and *load_weights*) and run (using *predict*) in another on a webserver. How can I also provide outputs from hidden layers and the network weights?

In some attempts of predicting on models of intermediate layers by creating models as below I have gotten an error including "tensor is not an element of this graph".

```
for modelLayer in mModel.layers:
    if not modelLayer.output == mModel.input:
        intermediateModel = keras.models.Model(inputs=mModel.input, outputs=modelLayer.output)
        layerActivations = intermediateModel.predict(np.array([inputs]))[0]
```

When attempting to get the weights using a session generated in the origin thread (*mSess*)

```
mModel.layers[1].weights[0].eval(session=mSess)
```

I get the error:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Error while reading resource variable dense/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense/kernel)
>
> [[Node: dense/kernel/Read/ReadVariableOp = ReadVariableOpdtype=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

In attempts to return the layer weights using a new session and the appropriate graph

```
sess = tf.Session(graph=mModel.output.graph)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
mModel.layers[1].weights[0].eval(session=sess)
```

I get the error:

> ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "init"
>   op: "NoOp" is not an element of this graph.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "tensor is not an element of this graph" can be resolved by using the graph associated with a tensor in the model.

```
with mModel.output.graph.as_default():
    for modelLayer in mModel.layers:
        if not modelLayer.output == mModel.input:
            intermediateModel = keras.models.Model(inputs=mModel.input, outputs=modelLayer.output)
            layerActivations = intermediateModel.predict(np.array([inputs]))[0]
```

**Edit: Updated Solution**

While the original solution below fixes the problem reported, the values provided for the weights using *...eval(sess)* are initialized values and not learned values or values that *predict* uses. There may be a way to use *eval* to get the proper result, but I am not aware of it. The alternative solution I found is to use *get_weights()* on the model or layer, as in:

```
mModel.get_weights()
mModel.layers[1].get_weights()
```

**Original solution**

The problem with resolving the weights is a combination of using the proper graph and initializing the session with the weights' initializer rather than the global initializer.

```
sess = tf.Session(graph=mModel.output.graph)
weights = modelLayer.weights[0]
sess.run(weights.initializer)
weightsValues = weights.eval(session=sess)
```

These solutions work across threads.